# display contact from the android file system path using cordova+ionic+android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to display a contact picture which in this path content://com.android.contacts/contacts/16954/photo as pointed out by my console log. But how much ever i try using various methods i am not able to do so. Please help.

I have also used the window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL method. But it always goes to the fail callback function.

Comment: In the future, please post at least one snippet of code that you /have/ tried; it shows that you have tried, and gives people a place to start. Have you tried to load that URL using a web browser or curl? I'm not familiar with the APIs involved here, but the most obvious thing here is that this path is not an invalid URL in the first place, unless the API will intelligently flip the URI around (into contacts.android.com).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding. 
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/create-delete-search-contacts-ionic-framework/
I have followed all of the steps listed in this article. 
.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {

$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob|content):|data:image\//);

}]);

Then in the HTML use

<img ng-src="{{contact.photos[0].value}}" ng-if="contact.photos.length &gt; 0"/>
This is how we add the photos value in ionic android. It still doesnt work for me. I know its not a valid url. But that is the output i am getting for photos.value.